# Adding watermark on image

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I'm looking for a way of adding watermark on image with **minimal** lossing of quality. Could anyone help me? Watermark can be a text or an image.

Comment: do you want a visible or invisible watermark?

Comment: What do mean in an invisible watermark? Transparent? Rather I need an transparent watermark.

Comment: The watermarks you describe exist in the image data. I'm talking about watermarks that live in the metadata or hide out in the image's data structure. A trivial example would be inserting a copyright string in the EXIF data. A more sophisticated example would involve several apparently unrelated pieces of EXIF data that can be combined into a checksum. Which you prefer depends on your objective.

Comment: Then I mean a visible watermark.

Comment: That's easy, you just need to blit a transparent image on top of your main image. You will probably want [transparentBlit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc533117.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

How about this method for adding image as a watermark to image

```
 public static void AddWaterMark(MemoryStream ms, string watermarkText, MemoryStream outputStream)
        {
            System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
            Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(img);
            Font font = new Font("Tahoma", (float)40);
            Color color = Color.FromArgb(50, 241, 235, 105);
            double tangent = (double)img.Height / (double)img.Width;
            double angle = Math.Atan(tangent) * (180 / Math.PI);
            double halfHypotenuse = Math.Sqrt((img.Height * img.Height) + (img.Width * img.Width)) / 2;
            double sin, cos, opp1, adj1, opp2, adj2;

            for (int i = 100; i > 0; i--)
            {
                font = new Font("Tahoma", i, FontStyle.Bold);
                SizeF sizef = gr.MeasureString(watermarkText, font, int.MaxValue);

                sin = Math.Sin(angle * (Math.PI / 180));
                cos = Math.Cos(angle * (Math.PI / 180));
                opp1 = sin * sizef.Width;
                adj1 = cos * sizef.Height;
                opp2 = sin * sizef.Height;
                adj2 = cos * sizef.Width;

                if (opp1 + adj1 < img.Height && opp2 + adj2 < img.Width)
                    break;
                //
            }

            StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat();
            stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            stringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

            gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            gr.RotateTransform((float)angle);
            gr.DrawString(watermarkText, font, new SolidBrush(color), new Point((int)halfHypotenuse, 0), stringFormat);
             gr.DrawImage(position, size, overlayImage) //  It helps if your image-to-overlay is loaded from a PNG file (with transparency) to produce the best quality.

            img.Save(outputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
```

Comment: Does this method save the image with watermark in high quality?

Comment: It doesn't compile because of this line ---gr.DrawImage(position, size, overlayImage); position, size and overlayImage are undefined.